# Dictionary won't be displayed as requested

Tags: python, list, dictionary, frequency, items

I need to solve an exercise (for beginners!) and get as result the frequencies of all occurring characters in a given text. My problem is I am stuck with the function I have tried to write because instead of a dictionary I get a list as result. I am aware that the problem is probably to be found in the use of "[]" but I haven't found any better solution to get at least one result.

Here is what I am struggling with:

```
def character_frequency(text):
"""
Returns the frequences of all occuring characters in the given text
:param text: A text
:return: Dict in the form {"<character>": frequency, "<character>": frequency, ...}
"""

frequency = {}  # empty dict

    for line in text:
    for character in line.lower():
        if character in frequency:
            frequency[character] += 1
        else:
            frequency[character] = 1
            print(f"character{str(frequency)}")

return frequency

print()
print("excerise")
frequency = character_frequency(growing_plants)
for c, n in frequency.items():
    print(f"Character: {c}: {n}")
```

How should I change my function in order to get the correct dictionary result?

Comment: By fixing your indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I noticed your indentation is wrong.

```
def character_frequency(text):
"""
Returns the frequences of all occuring characters in the given text
:param text: A text
:return: Dict in the form {"<character>": frequency, "<character>": frequency, ...}
"""
# Finding most occuring character

# Set frequency as empty dictionary
frequency_dict = {}

for character in string:
    if character in frequency_dict:
        frequency_dict[character] += 1
    else:
        frequency_dict[character] = 1

most_occurring = max(frequency_dict, key=frequency_dict.get)

# Displaying result
print("\nMost occuring character is: ", most_occuring)
print("It is repeated %d times" %(frequency_dict[most_occurring]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def character_frequency(text):
    """
    Returns the frequences of all occuring characters in the given text
    :param text: A text
    :return: Dict in the form {"<character>": frequency, "<character>": frequency, ...}
    """

    frequency = {}  # empty dict

    for line in text:
        for character in line.lower():
            if character in frequency:
                frequency[character] += 1
            else:
                frequency[character] = 1

    return frequency

growing_plants = "Returns the frequences of all occuring characters in the given text"
print()
print("excerise")
frequency = character_frequency(growing_plants)
print(frequency)
# for c, n in frequency.items():
#     print(f"Character: {c}: {n}")
```

Output:

```
{'r': 6, 'e': 9, 't': 6, 'u': 3, 'n': 5, 's': 3, ' ': 10, 'h': 3, 'f': 2, 'q': 1, 'c': 5, 'o': 2, 'a': 3, 'l': 2, 'i': 3, 'g': 2, 'v': 1, 'x': 1}
```

Comment: thank you very much! somehow it keeps on showing a list as result instead of the output you suggested. I'll try to figure out which information I should add to it.